# Thought process behind data analysis

Tags: dataset, books

I am looking for books/tutorials that help you gain the insight into the thought process behind data analysis.

Most of the books I've read were mostly documentation - the author shows you a function and some data that he applies that function to. They also show how to use graphs and how histogram/boxplots etc. work. They go through popular libraries like numpy, pandas and how to use them.

I am interested in how people on (for example) Kaggle in their kernels on Titanic get their ideas from, on what to apply to datasets. Those people know which columns to plot as a function of each other, when to plot histograms, when to plot density functions and so on.

I am somewhat experienced in Machine Learning. It's pretty obvious which algorithm can be applied to what situation. Data exploring seems like a very ambiguous exercise with many solutions/ideas.

Another way to put is: Where to get the ideas for data exploration from?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your current level of competence and sophistication is in your data analysis journey and how much math and statistics you understand.

But if you have already gotten through and understood calculus and elementary linear algebra and either intermediate statistics at the upper division college level (doesn't have to be an actual course you took for credits, just the equivalent rigor of material and time and effort put towards mastering it), i.e. statistical analysis and modeling, using multivariate regressions and that sort of thing or you have gotten through the equivalent level in the machine learning sphere, then HANDS DOWN the best book of this kind I have ever come across is a handbook, and there are like 7 or 8 editions to it I believe called "A Guide to Econometrics."

There should be books like this for every technical field in my opinion, it is filled with insights, rules of thumb, tools of the trade, and common Language explanations without the need for proofs about how to do your analysis and what usually happens in practice as opposed to in the textbooks!

Beyond that book, I would recommend checking out any of Nassim Taleb's popular books on risk, probability, decision making in the real world, applied metastastiscs, and a host of other things as well.
Their titles are:

- Fooled by Randomness
- The Black Swan
- Antifragile
- Skin in the Game

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is more about "What would be the most informative (and easy readable) way to visualize one specific problem?". Having a specific question in mind you can explore galleries of the libraries with their examples, for instance,  [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html). You could also explore another kernels to see how people visualized it. For some question there are pretty trivial solutions. Other questions can be visualized in very many different ways but what counts is how readable and informative your plot is.

In case of titanic imagine three questions that you want to visualize.

1. What if survival rate depends somehow on the age and/or sex? 

   For this you might want to choose a density or histogram with having two curves on the plot: for survival and non-survival. Maybe you want to split the plot into two plots for female and male. 
   [image]

2. What if survival rate depends on a Pclass? Or maybe Emarked as well? And maybe sex plays also an important role?

    
   I am a fan of factor plots as you can introduce lots of information into it and it is quite understandable from the first sight. So, you see that 1st and 2nd class had a higher survival rate comparing to the 3rd class. (The next question can arise: For each embark what is the relative proportion of the pclass? What would be the better visualization?)
   [image]

3. What if a survival rate depends on the pclass and age? Additionally you could see what is the age distribution of each class.

   Violin plots might be good for that.
   [image]